# Laravel Eloquent - id to name relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using eloquent in Laravel 4 at moment and I want to join all two tables. My current sql is:

```
SELECT h.project_status_id, s.name FROM project_history as h LEFT JOIN project_status as s ON h.project_status_id = s.project_status_id;
```

If it helps I have an eloquent relationship set up.

```
ProjectBaseModel::find($project_id)->history;
```

I am grabbing all the history entries that belong to a particular project however there is a **project_status_id** on the **project_history** table and when i show it in the view i want to replace the **project_status_id** with its **string name** in the **project_status** table.

e.g.

Table: Project_History

```
------------------- ---------------
| project_status_id| comment       |
------------------- ---------------
| 2                | Comment 2     |
------------------  ---------------
| 4                | Comment 4     |
------------------  ---------------
| 5                | Comment 5     |
------------------  ---------------
```

Table: Project_Status

```
------------------ -----------
|project_status_id| name      |
------------------ -----------
| 2               | Status 2  |
------------------ -----------
| 4               | Status 4  |
------------------ -----------
| 5               | Status 5  |
------------------ -----------
```

Desired table:

```
 ----------- -----------
| name      | comment   |
 ----------- -----------
| Status 2  | Comment 2 |
 ----------- -----------
| Status 4  | Comment 4 |
------------------------
| Status 5  | Comment 5 |
------------------------
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I can't find a question or an issue.

Comment: here it is sorry, i did a table up to support my question

Comment: Use `withPivot` on the `belongsToMany` definition, then you can access it via `$project->pivot->whateverFieldFromPivot`. Your question is very unclear anyway.